# warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion ArrayList <String> - Proyecto Restaurante

Tags: java, netbeans

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando compilo mi proyecto me salen estas advertencias, pero no se como solucionarlo, el proyecto luego de compilado no hace nada, solo muestra la interfaz grafica y ya, estoy utlizado NetBeans, tambien les dejo algunos metodos donde utilizo estas listas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este metodo lo tengo en una clase llamada Pedidos que utilizo para acceder a la informacion de la BD

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y aca lo que hago es mostrar la informacion al usuario en el panel grafico

Comment: El código siempre _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Hola Dario, bienvenido, un "warning" no afecta el funcionamiento de un programa, es solo un aviso, si tu programa no hace lo que esperas, el problema es otro, para poder ayudarte, necesitamos ver tu código, si es muy largo, las partes involucradas, y siempre como texto. por el lado de las quejas, **lgDao** y similares, devuelven objetos `List` que no fueron creados asi: **List<Algo> algo = new ArrayList<>();** sino asi: **List algo = new ArrayList();** por eso te avisa de la conversión no `checkeada`, ya que no sabe lista de "que" es **algo**.

Comment: Hola muchas gracias si tenias razon, el problema radicaba en el build.xml ya que no le estaba especificando cual era la clase principal por lo tanto no funcionaba.

Comment: Dario, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta, elimines las imágenes, y agregues tu código y los "warnnigs" como texto, así evitarás recibir votos negativos, por otro lado, podrías responder tu propia pregunta y luego marcarla como aceptada, de esa forma estarás ayudando a otros, y tal vez recibas algún puntito de "regalo".